# How Do I Horizontally Center UICollectionViewCells With Paging Enabled? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have built a collectionView that I would like to mainly display one movie poster in the center of the view. I will have around 20 movies to display in the collectionView so I would like to show a tiny bit of the next movie on the right edge, and when I move over to the next page, the movie in focus will be centered, with the previous and next movie poking out respectively on the left and right side.

With the way that I have my code, when I page to the next movie, the next movie is not centered at all, it moved far too much to the right on the x-axis. How do I go about programmatically setting the distance that paging will require? How can I achieve the ability for the collectionView to properly center the pages after the first?

Paging is enabled on my collectionView. I have not created a custom collectionViewFlowLayout.

[Screenshots of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijdct.jpg)
[Video of my issue](https://youtu.be/14yV3qgotsA)

Here is my collectionView and scrollView code:

```
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let posterWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.height / 3) * 2
    return CGSizeMake(posterWidth, collectionView.frame.size.height)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let posterWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.height / 3) * 2
    let horizontalInset = (collectionView.frame.size.width - posterWidth) / 2
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, horizontalInset, 0, horizontalInset)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
}

---------------

extension MainViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let index = Int(collectionView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.frame.size.width)
    let movie = movies[index]
    updateViews(movie)
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
[yourCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: This code is not even Swift. And even if you wrote it in Swift, it does not help to solve OP's problem at all.